# Identify this Sot-23-5 Linear Regulator

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify this 5 pin SOT-23 regulator. It's labeled S80D (Maybe S8OD, the letter O not number 0). But a search for that top code does not come up with anything specific to it.

[image]

I do not recognize the logo used. It looks like a comma, or a lopsided rainbow. I have searched for the manufacturer logo on a few sites but nothing matches. Since it's not even an initial or recognizable shape, I can't even narrow it down.

***No, it's not broken.***

Comment: It is almost impossible to tell which it really is, the codes are not unique and the part might be counterfeit anyways. Try smdcode.com it tells me that it *may* be a rico RP103x LDO or anything compatible. The real question is: what are you planning to do with the knowledge, and if there is a better way to deal with this

Comment: @PlasmaHH I know that the top-code alone isn't that useful or unique, but combined with the package, it being a regulator, and especially having a manufacturers logo is should eventually be identifiable.  The main reason I want this is because I don't recognize the manufacturer, and I would like to know it's specs (max input, if its fixed or adjustable, and if adj, the formula)

Comment: Caveat about counterfeit parts still apply. Especially since this looks like an arduino nano. And even the real ones seem to use different LDOs all the time. So it would only apply to the one you have (or the series). So when it is only about the one you have, replacing that one with a known LDO if you need to rely on the parameters seems to make more sense to me. If you want to rely on the nano in general, it makes only sense to rely on the parameters they advertise since for the next production run they might chose anothr.

Comment: I have found two more IC-s with this logo, [one](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCS-X-MP3-regulator-IC-Marking-65K5-Marking-Code-Query/32520807237.html), [two](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/LDO-Voltage-Regulator-IC-ME6211-ME6211C12M5G-ME6211C12-SOT23-5/233189_32463838932.html). But nothing more, it is maybe from a Japanese manufacturer, not certain.

Comment: Well, it is probably not adjustable. At least it doesn't look like there is a divider on the output. You might be in a better position to judge that. And if it IS adjustable, the voltage at the feedback node can be directly measured.

Comment: That logo seems to be used by "Nanjing Micro One Electronics Inc".

Comment: @brhans if you want to add that as an answer, with a link to their page or normal logo, I'd accept it. Since they don't have downloadable datasheets, I doubt an identification down to the part is feasible.

Comment: I have that on 5V 16mhz arduino pro mini so i guess is a 5V regulator

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any real point to this question, and it keeps attracting problematic responses.  If it is fixed or adjustable (and if adjustable the reference voltage) can be readily recognized from the surrounding topology.  If you want to know how it performs, characterize but **but you can't trust another to be the same**.  So, if you need one with known performance, simply replace the regulator.  Two minute job...  For that matter, if it is important you may want to have your own boards made where the other parts are known too.

Answer (score 1):

cannot name the manufacturer, however on my Pro Micros and Minis (all "counterfeit Chinese knockoffs" which I would rephrase as "inexpensive and reliable open source providers from China) the regulators are labeled S2PC, S80C, S80D (micros) and S8PL (mini), all with the same manufacturer symbol.  I have tested the dropout voltage and measured 240 mV at 65 mA load.

Answer (score 0):

From the Arduino forum website Input Voltage is 3.5 to 16v. Max continuous current 150mA. Even if the LDO is not full-spec, you should be good up to 12v into 'raw'.

Answer (score -2):

It's a counterfeit 3.3v LDO, common on Chinese Arduino Pro Mini knockoffs.

Source: I have one sitting in front of me.

Comment: What makes it counterfeit?